# How can i create and populate my database on my webapp's first startup?

Tags: java, jpa, tomcat, jdbc, apache-tomee

I'm using TomEE 8.0.9. I should distribute a webapp in its .war format. In order to ensure an easy installation I want the database (specified in `resources.xml`) to be automatically created with all its tables and some initial records (By means of a .sql file).

I tried with a class that gets executed on startup but it gets problematic if the database isn't connected during the webapp's deploy. Isn't there a way to do an action when a JDBC connection gets created for the first time? Tomcat offers the `initSQL` parameter but it just works with one single statement.

In general, what it the best way to create a database on the app's first startup?

Comment: [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) is popular for this (and does much more).

Comment: @TimMoore It seems that the maven plugin only works when building the project (or by calling the mvn goal manually). Should i programmatically run Flyway in a class that runs on startup in order to get it to work on runtime?

Comment: Right, there’s an API you can call https://flywaydb.org/documentation/getstarted/firststeps/api

Comment: Are you using JPA?

Comment: @rzo1 yes, I'm using Hibernate 5.6.2

Comment: I would suggest to use "validate" via Hibernate, generate the schema via Hibernate in the build process (it is really simple to generate and write into a file), and then use Liquibase/Flyway for populating or migrating.

Comment: Typically this step can be automated via CI/CD and does not need to be an Singleton Startup Bean in your application. If you do not care, you can let the JPA provider update / create your schema on app startup (useful for testing)  and use Flyway or some Java Code to add Initial data.